# Update Windows 10 to the latest build on Dell Vostro 3550

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, dell-vostro

On my Dell Vostro 3550, I have updated from Windows 7 to Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and then finally to Windows 10 when it was launched. I have noticed recently that my machine is not running the latest build and is still running build 10240 which I believe is the release build.

I have tried fixing Windows update errors and updating the system to latest build, but every time it fails without giving much insight to the error. I have checked Dell Website and this model is not listed for November update [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN297954).

I want to know if someone has succeeded in updating to Windows 10 on this model and if yes, what steps can I follow to do the same. If the answer is No, please guide me with other available options.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Windows version is valid, I would simply call Microsoft.  They will probably remote desktop into your machine in order to figure out what exactly is going on.  Recently I had some issues w/my Windows Machine and they had to do that in order to Activate some software that wasn't activating.  I believe they'll do something similar w/your situation.

Comment: Take a look at this answer; although you are not talking about insider builds the same principle applies. Method 2 will fix this for you. http://superuser.com/questions/1036925/windows-10-insider-preview-can-i-force-an-update/1071497#1071497

Comment: @Argonauts Thanks for the link. I do not find install.esd file on my drive. what to do now?

Comment: @Dale, That's the last thing i would like to do even though my windows version is a valid one :)

Comment: If you haven't already tried this, run the automated windows update repair tool located here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058

Comment: @Argonauts Have already tried and re-checked for updates. It updates some s/w (in general Defender definitions) for 1 single time and then fails to update Windows again. :(

Comment: Here's the link of what i see here - http://imgur.com/trjZv50

Answer (score 0):

i have Dell Vostro 3550 and I fully updated the machine but i'm still running build 10240 of the windows 10,. it seems its natural but i think you can download the latest ISO file of the windows 10 and install it from scratch.

Comment: Doesn't work :(