# Windows 10 not Upgrading to new builds

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-insider

I'm a registered Windows Insider. Now I am in build 10586. I can't get more builds. When i click 'Check for Updates' it writes 'Your Device is Up To Date.'
Can anyone help me?

Also, can I update from 10586 to Redstone builds?

Sorry for my Bad English.

[image: Here is the image for the Update Settings.]

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/1036925/windows-10-insider-preview-can-i-force-an-update

Comment: get an ISo of Build 14332, mount the ISO, run setup and select upgrade. Now look if Window detects in the next weeks a new build.

Comment: I don't understand, 10586 is the current build, unless you you opt into the Preview Builds.  If you recently went to 10586, it takes awhile, to be offered Preview Builds.  **can I update from 10586 to Redstone builds?** - You can use the current Insider Preview .ISO to force yourself to those builds.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at present, the latest Windows 10 version is 10586.240, which is released on April 28, but I haven’t received this version update, my current system is 10586.218.

So, since your system build is 10586, I think it is the correct and latest build.

In addition, I find out a documentation talks about Windows 10 Insider Preview Build, please refer to it for assistance.

http://www.askvg.com/new-update-build-of-windows-10-technical-preview-now-available-for-download/

Regards